# NotificationCenter help for Swift - how to use addObserver?

Tags: ios, swift, notificationcenter

I have a notification center call that looks like this, and I'm trying to create an observer for it, which just calls a function in the same Swift file:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(
    name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "JSON"), 
    object: [ "json" : "user@domain.com" ])
```

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, 
    selector: #selector(receiveJsNotification(_:)), 
    name: NSNotification.Name ("JSON"), object: nil)
```

then later in my Swift file, I have:

```
@objc
func receiveJsNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
   print("received notification");
   // how do I retrieve user@domain.com value?
}
```

However "received notification" is never printed, even though the "post" and "addObserver" lines (which I have in separate functions of the same class) are definitely executed (print statements show).

My Swift builds without error. I'm using Xcode 14.2

What am I doing wrong? Also, how do I retrieve the "user@domain.com" value?

Comment: Is the call to `addObserver` being made before (in time) the call to `post`?

Comment: yes, definitely

Comment: to answer your second question, the data you provided is in `notification.userInfo`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what ended up working for me:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(receiveJsNotification(_:)),
                        name: NSNotification.Name ("JSON"), object: nil)


    // elsewhere in the app, we pass the value...
    let value = "some value";

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "JSON"), object: nil, userInfo: ["json" : value]) 

    return true
}


@objc
func receiveJsNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    let jsonValue = notification.userInfo as AnyObject?
    
    if (jsonValue !== nil) {
        let someValue = jsonValue?.object(forKey: "json") ?? ""
        // do something with someValue here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your code doesn't work. I just banged out an example project using the default iPhone application template (using Storyboards)

Here is the code for the ViewController class:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let testNotification = NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "testNotification")

    @IBAction func sendNotification(_ sender: Any) {
        print("In \(#function)")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: testNotification, object: nil)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(notifificationReceived), name: testNotification, object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func notifificationReceived(_ theNotificaiton: Notification) {
        print("Notification received")
    }
}
```

When I wire up the IBAction of that code to a button, run the app, and tap the button, I see a "Notification received" message appear on the console, telling me it works

Obviously this is an incredibly naive example that sends a notification to the same object (The view controller) that listens for it, but it proves that the notification center works.

Comment: See the update to my answer. I provided working example code that observes notifications, then posts them and logs to the console when the notification is received.

Answer (score 0):

To made your code work pass the data in userinfo instead of object like on below line, Also make sure your addObserver code runs before posting the notification.

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "JSON"), object: nil, userInfo: ["json" : "your email/data"])
```

In your `receiveJSNotification()` add the following code

```
if let email = notification.userInfo?["json"] as? String {
        // do something with your image   
}
```

notification object you received in function has the userInfo dictionary which holds the data you passed when calling the observer. You can get the data from dictionary and unwrap using `if let/guard let`